Is it UB to read bytes from malloc() without initializing them first?
In C, if I malloc(N) a buffer, for what operations is that buffer valid? E.g.

a buffer starting at malloc(N) is invalid for reads until initialized
a buffer starting at malloc(N) is valid for writes of at least size N (but maybe greater).


In C it depends. You're allowed to read and use (non-pointer) uninitialized data unless the indeterminate value happens to be a trap representation. Then it's UB. For pointers, dereferencing a pointer leads to UB, but for reading its value we're back to trap representations.

A better question would be "Why do you want to read uninitialized data?". You allocate a buffer to store data, not to read things that isn't there.

@BoP: Re “Why do you want to read uninitialized data?”: Eve is working on sneaking some malicious code into open-source software and wants to know whether code that reads freshly allocated memory is guaranteed to read the bytes in the memory or might be optimized into something else by the compiler. Don’t assume everybody is writing “normal” software. Security professionals need to understand how compilers and other software will behave in usual circumstances. This knowledge is also useful in debugging, as it helps deduce and eliminate causes of various symptoms.

@doliphin, I suspect reads via unsigned char * are maybe OK and others lead to UB.

@chux: Reads in this case with any satisfactory alignment have defined behavior. When reading uninitialized dynamically allocated memory, the effective type is the type used for the access, so there is no aliasing violation. However, the value is indeterminate, meaning the access does not actually have to read memory or produce a consistent value. So this is only barely defined: The operation will produce some value but it could be anything, not related to what is in memory.

When you use malloc(), each byte is uninitialized until you initialize it. So reading from it is like reading from any other uninitialized variable.
You can instead use calloc(), which automatically initializes all bytes to 0.
For writing, you can write at most N bytes, not greater.

Depending on the implementation, might the malloc() call not allocate slightly greater than you need, so is this not implementation defined, or is malloc() special-cased here?

It might. But there's no way to know, so it's UB to write past what you requested.

Any variable can have padding after it, but it's always UB to write there.

@doliphin: Even if a particular malloc implementation allocates more space than requested, that does not make it safe for a program to use. A compiler is allowed to rely on the specification of malloc in the C standard. So, if it sees a = malloc(32); and, later, b[35] = x;, where b has type char *, it is allowed to conclude that, since b[35] is outside the 32 bytes allocated to a, that b does not point to the memory allocated for a. This can cause “weird” optimization effects in the program if you are not aware of these things.

@doliphin Just because something is UB, it doesn't mean it has to be detected or cause an error. Sometimes UB can be innocuous, as when malloc allocates more space than you request. This is what makes it hard to detect, because testing won't uncover the problem and you may not notice it for years.

@Barmar Of course. But the question was whether or not the buffer returned by malloc(N) is known by the compiler to be of exactly N bytes, or if it is treated as a function like any other... as @Eric Postpischil states, malloc() is special-cased (i.e. the compiler is allowed to make assumptions about what it is).

There's nothing like that in the question. It asks whether it's UB. It doesn't matter what the compiler "knows", it's still UB. The compiler also knows about padding it adds between array variables, but that doesn't mean you can access out of array bounds.

The implementation may use this space internally, e.g. it's not uncommon for the space before the beginning of a malloc'ed block to contain the size of the block, so free() knows how big it is.

@doliphin The C standard specifies the behavior of malloc().  The compiler doesn't have to make any assumptions.  malloc(N) returns a pointer to an N-byte block, or it returns NULL.  Full stop.

malloc(n) will either return a null pointer or a pointer to n bytes which fulfill the alignment requirement of any object. Hence, the pointer can be cast to a pointer to any object with size at most n. Normally, the cast is done implicitly by assigning the return value of malloc to a pointer of the proper type.
Once the memory has been initialized through the given pointer, it is in almost all cases undefined behavior to access it as a different type.
It is undefined behavior to read or write beyond the n bytes.
Before the allocated memory has been initialized, it is ok to read it, but using the value is generally speaking undefined behavior.
